# Cascade de-excitation of a hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-optics

Suppose we have a hydrogen atom in the $n = 100$ level. It will decay into lower orbitals by emitting a photon. The problem is, there are many lower orbitals to choose from. It can decay into an $n = 99$ level, or an $ n = 10$ level, or the $n = 1$ level.

So, what are the proportions of all the channels?

Once the atom is in the $n = 90$ level, it can decay into a still lower level by emitting a second photon. So, it is really a cascade process.

In the end, the atom will set down on the $n = 1$ level. The question is, in the whole process, how many photons will be emitted on average?

We note that the $n=2$, $l=0$ state is a long-lived metastable state, because of the selection rule. Another question is then, with what probability will the atom decay into this metastable state and with what probability will it decay into the ground state?

Comment: One could, in principle, calculate the overlap integrals for a given energy state to all lower energy states, and do so for all levels. Yes, it is a cascade problem, but it turns out that a few transitions will dominate.